# Why is session count shown rather than using count when requesting ga:users through the Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, statistics, users, metrics

I requested data thru the [Google Analytics API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2016-06-14&end-date=2016-06-14&metrics=ga%3Ausers&dimensions=ga%3AdateHour) with the following parameters:

- start date: 2016-06-14
- end date: 2016-06-14
- metrics: ga:users
- dimensions: ga:dateHour

But looks like the result I get has session counts instead of [user counts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=user&jump=ga_users). Is it true? Or am I wrong?

API result:
[image: api result]

Web result:
[image: web result]